# SAP HANA how to read SID via SQL

Tags: sql, hana, system-information

How to read the Server Name and / or SID (SAP System Identification) via SQL in SAP HANA?

Answer (score 1):

the system monitoring view M_HOST_INFORMATION should hold the information you are looking for.

```
SELECT HOST, KEY, VALUE FROM SYS.M_HOST_INFORMATION WHERE KEY IN ('sid', 'net_publicname');
```

See the following link for a full documentation:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20b10028751910148c1c9de602d771de.html

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The *SELECT FROM M_HOST_INFORMATION* statement in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61667957/12066099) returns different host names. Depending on your use case you should use:

- The `HOST` column showing the logical host name, as the HANA instance was installed
- The `net_publicname` property showing the effective hostname or ip-address used for network communication, when additional connections are opened by client libraries